# Armature modifiers don't update when rendering animation

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

I have a four legged robot, I rigged it with a main body armature, and a leg rig I duplicated. The leg root bones each follow a target bone in the main rig with a "copy transforms" modifier. It works alright in viewport & renders, but for some reason when I render an animation, these modifiers don't update so the legs stay static. How to force modifiers before rendering?

Comment: have you made sure that the modifier's render option was enabled?

Comment: Yes, as I explained the modifier is applied when doing a single render.

Comment: could you please share a part of your file (only the necessary)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/0/5/0557fc93d58cc87297dab64e2031d1d6.blend

Comment: it looks like it doesn't take the constraints into account, maybe it's a circular dependency problem? Not sure why it works in preview though...

Comment: There's a hiccup in the viewport as if it does two passes of updates. Maybe it only does one when changing frames for rendering animations.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a circular dependency, caused by a damped track using a bone within the IK chain.